# Attempting to index a number value. C++ & Lua

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to write a kind of engine that uses Lua as a script language. It gives me the error in the title.

```
#define el Engine::lua
int vecCreate(lua_State* vm) {
    int argc = el.argc();
    el.createTable();
    if (argc == 0) {
        el.tableAddd("x", 0.0);
        el.tableAddd("y", 0.0);
    } else if (argc == 2) {
        el.tableAddd("x", el.argd());
        el.tableAddd("y", el.argd());
    }
    return 1;
}
void Lua::createTable() {
    lua_createtable(vm, 2, 0);
    }
void Lua::tableAddd(string key, double val) {
    lua_pushstring(vm, key.c_str());
    lua_pushnumber(vm, val);
    lua_settable(vm, -3);
}
double Lua::argd() {
    double res = lua_tonumber(vm, 1);
    lua_pop(vm, 1);
    return res;
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? The whole script is

```
function draw()
    drawColor(100, 100, 100)
    drawPoly(vecNew(10, 10), vecNew(10, 100), vecNew(100, 100), vecNew(100, 10))
end
```

Yes, I'm sure that the problem is in the draw function

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason you aren't using luabind, SWIG, or lua-icxx? I've used the latter together with SWIG in same program and it's saved me a ton of time.

Comment: Yeah, the reason is boost for luabind. And total laziness for all of them. I don't want to learn again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I've just pushed a table on the stack in `vecCreate` before getting the arguments